# Running jar file / .class file along with a properties file

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

I have an eclipse project that uses a Properties file. The file is located in the root directory of the project. I want to be able to run the .class file that eclipse builds using the cmd (in windows).

I use this code to get the properties from the file:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream("DBConfig.properties");
prop.load(fileStream);
```

but when I run the .class file I get this error:

> couldn't read property file...

How can I do this?

I also did see a post similar to this, but he needed to override a system property, which I don’t: [Execute a jar with an external properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128086/execute-a-jar-with-an-external-properties-file).

Comment: Place the properties file where your .class file reside

Comment: tried that didnt help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the property file on your classpath and read it as a resource.

If you need to provide external configuration (e.g., changeable by editing the text file) then use a command line parameter or system parameter (e.g., `-Dconfig=/a/full/path`) to locate the file.

Comment: thank u it worked but i had to move the properties file into the src folder , in root didnt work

Comment: @saeedhardan Because it needs to be on the classpath if you're using it as a resource.

Answer (score 1):

try passing properties file as parameter something like below

```
java -jar <jar name> -DDBConfig.properties=<Path>
```

And code will be something like

```
FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("DBConfig.properties"));
```